# Why does `catch (Exception $e)` not handle this `ErrorException`?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I get the `ErrorException` on the function call bellow. How can this be? Why is it not caught?

```
try {
    static::$function_name($url);
}
catch (Exception $e) {}
```

The underlying reason for the error is a `file_put_contents` call. I'm using the Laravel 4 framework, if it makes any difference.

Comment: get an `ErrorException` escaping that `try`/`catch` block. Create a testcase.

Comment: Im having this problem too...

Comment: You aren't in a namespace are you? You would have to write it as `\Exception` then, to reference the root namespace.

Comment: I think you're right! As you can see this was long ago, but I once had something similar and adding \ fixed it. Make an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I suspect that you need to write this:

```
try {
    static::$function_name($url);
} catch (\Exception $e) {}
```

Note the \ in front of Exception.

When you have declared a namespace, you need to specify the root namespace in front of classes like Exception, otherwise the catch block here will be looking for `\Your\Namespace\Exception`, and not just `\Exception`

Comment: Or `use Exception;` in your current namespace