# Laravel won't catch ErrorException

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to catch an exception when sending an email, but Laravel won't do it. I read that Laravel turns every warning and error into an ErrorException but that doesn't seem to be working in my case.

```
$transportExchange = new SmtpTransport($myHost, 25, 'tls');
$transportExchange->setUsername('...');
$transportExchange->setPassword('...');
$configExchange = new Swift_Mailer($transportExchange);

try {
    Mail::setSwiftMailer($configExchange);
    Mail::to($email['to'])->send(new GeneralEmail($email));
} catch (ErrorException $ex) {
    do_something();
}
```

When the password is not correct, I'm getting a Laravel error screen showing stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

But instead of that I want to reach the do_something() statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`catch (Exception $e)\` not handle this \`ErrorException\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071191/why-does-catch-exception-e-not-handle-this-errorexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three days I found the answer in here: [Why does `catch (Exception $e)` not handle this `ErrorException`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071191/why-does-catch-exception-e-not-handle-this-errorexception)

This is what I needed to do:

```
try {
    static::$function_name($url);
} catch (\Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: This answer is just a close vote in disguise.